# How to share buffers between linux kernel modules

Tags: linux, module, kernel, buffer, driver

I am working on a kernel module which needs to work on data from another module. how to share the buffer?

I have tried using EXPORT_SYMBOL to access the array

```
char my_test_buffer[100];

EXPORT_SYMBOL(my_test_buffer);
```

How to access this in the other module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
extern char * my_test_buffer;

my_test_buffer[0] = 1;
```

Note you will only be able to load the user module after the provider module.

Comment: thanks gby . This buffer being a shared data between two modules how to keep up access conflicts and  sync read/write between the two modules?

Comment: Like any other shared buffer from two contexts - use synchronization mechanisms such as spin locks, mutexes, sequence locks or even RCU

Comment: Is there any other way sharing buffer instead of exporting in kernel ?